# Having problem with having a fraction result

Tags: r

I was trying to solve a basic matrix problem. .

I used :

```
A<- matrix(c(2,7,5,7), 2,2)
b<- c(8,12)
solve(A,b, fractions = TRUE)
```

However, my result only gives me results in decimal places. How can get fractions results?

I also want to plot this equation above.
I used:

```
plotEqn(A,b)
```

However, it tells me this equation can't be found. Can I have some advice please?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: `fractions` is not an argument of that function.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question,

```
MASS::fractions(solve(A,b))
```

gives {4/21, 32/21} (note that you won't always be guaranteed the correct answer, as R does floating-point calculation unlike e.g. Mathematica)

For your second question, it looks like the `plotEqn()` function is in the `matlib` package: if you have that package installed, then either first loading the package (with `library("matlib")`) or `matlib::plotEqn(A,b)` should work.

On closer inspection it looks like you want `matlib::Solve()` for the first question (note that R is case-sensitive, so `solve` and `Solve` are different):

```
library(matlib)
Solve(A,b, fraction=TRUE)
## x1    =   4/21 
## x2  =  32/21
```